# выполнение по времени python

Tags: python, время

чего то туплю!
нужно чтоб функция выполнялась в каждые 5 мин 1 сек **строго**
т.е  в
10:45:01
10:55:01
11:05:01
и тд.

проблема в том что не понятно в какое время запустится программа и еще моя функция может выполнять ся разный промежуток времени, т.е. банально **time.sleep(300)** не подойдет

```
while true:
    tt1 = datetime.datetime.now().minute % 5 * 60 + datetime.datetime.now().second
    tt = 300
    if not (300 - tt1):
        tt = 301 - tt1 
    time.sleep(tt)
    my_code()
```

Comment: а что вот этим кодом хотелось сказать `if not (300 - tt1)` ?

Comment: Вы это хотите "вручную" сделать обязательно? Проще взять готовую библиотеку `schedule` или как её там.

Comment: В вашем подходе есть маленькая уязвимость, в синтетике врятли вы ее встретите, а вот в проде - наверняка, у вас нет гарантии что sleep будет длится ровно столько сколько вы сказали, если система загружена и у нее нет ресурсов на обработку вашего кода - он будет отодвинут от времени планирумого пробуждения до момента пока более приоритетные задачи не будут выполнены. т.е. вы сказали sleep(1000) а код реально проспал не 1000мсек, а 1200, и нужная секунда могла уже закончится...

Comment: да тут ещё целая пачка всего. Если нужно именно в *:*:01, значит скорее всего в *:*:0 происходит что то интересное и хочется поймать это как можно раньше.

Answer (score 3):

спасибо за советы!! нашел способ! Хотя может есть оригинальнее решение?

```
import schedule
import time

def my_code():
    print("I'm working...")


schedule.every(5).minutes.at(":01").do(my_code)


while True:
    schedule.run_pending()        
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Если ваш код запускается на линукс. Рекомендую использовать нативные средства systemd. Гораздо надежней